# Best way to Install Lampp setup on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php5, lamp, xampp

What is the best way to install a lampp setup in ubuntu? I know to install using xampp. Is it ok for using as a central development server?

Or if am installing individually what are the packages i have to install?

Is the below packages enough?

```
PHP
Mysql
Apache
```

Answer (score 1):

- Linux - you have Ubuntu ✔
- Apache - `sudo apt-get install apache2`
- MySQL - `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
- PHP - `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`

There are more detailed instructions over on [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) too.

To do it all in one

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```